# Error when trying to run import pytube with aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud9-ide

Hello I'm trying to import pytube in my lambda function but i get the following error when I try to run the code:

> Response {
>       "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index'" }
>
> Function Logs Unable to import module 'index': No module named
>   'pytube'

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
from pytube import YouTube

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

URL = ''
PATH = ''

def handler(event, context):
    YouTube(URL).streams.first().download(PATH)
```

And my IDE says pytube is already installed:

> Requirement already satisfied: pytube in
>   /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that it works locally, but does not work when you try and run it on lambda?

Comment: Yes exactly it works in the command line interface but not with lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not including your dependencies in your deployment package.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#deployment-pkg-for-virtualenv for full details, but effectively you must do:

```
pip install pytube -t /path/to/project-dir
```

Before making the zip file for uploading.

(Note that `boto3` is an exception to this rule, as AWS automatically include it for you, on the assumption that your lambda probably works with AWS services!)